# How to convert multidimensional $_POST name to HTML name

Tags: php

Let's say I have this input

```
<input name="person[name][first]">
```

I can read the POST with PHP

```
$_POST['person']['name']['first'];
```

Now, I want to convert that person data array with PHP to use it for the `name` attribute in HTML. How do I do that in PHP???

`$_POST['person']['name']['first']` to `person[name][first]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your example variable and nested array, you could loop through like so:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key=>$data ){
    if( is_array( $data ) ){
        foreach( $data as $subkey=>$subdata ){
            if( is_array( $subdata ) ){
                foreach( $subdata as $sub2key=>$sub2data ){
                    echo "My name is: " . $key . '[' . $subkey . '][' . $sub2key . ']';
                }
            } else {
                echo "My name is: " . $key . '[' . $subkey . ']';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated: what if I wanted to use multidimensional array?

Comment: You can nest another loop. If you go deeper and deeper it would be wise to write a recursive function. Update above.